# For Loop - How to get-assign the index of the last element in an array to the first element as an ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, indexing

I am building a new array of objects via a For loop and need to assign each new object an Id. I need each new Id to be the bottom value of the array's new length.

The current code is something like this:

```
var setData = function(data) {

  var newData = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (Util.checkType(data[i].typeId)) {
      newData.push(data[i]);
      data[i].id = i;
    }
  }
  this.data = newData;
};
```

The way it's currently being done results in each new Id = the object's index in the newData array. I need to the opposite of the results I'm getting.

So if data.length = 50, for example, and all 50 pass the conditional, I need the first element to have an "Id": 49 with the last "Id: 0.

I've tried iterating backwards and tracing:

```
  for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (Util.checkType(data[i].typeId)) {
    data[i].id = i;
    newData.push(data[i]);
      console.log("newData.length", newData.length);
      console.log("data[i].id", data[i].id);
    }
  }
  console.log("newData", newData);
  this.data = newData;
```

But even though I can see:

```
newData.length 1
data[i].id 49

newData.length 2
data[i].id 48

newData.length 3
data[i].id 47
```

and so on down, each object in the final newData array still has an Id = the object's index in the array.

```
newData = [
  {"address": 123 Main St,
   "duration": some hours or minutes, 
   "Id": 0},
  {"address": 1234 Main St,
   "duration": some hours or minutes, 
   "Id": 1},
   etc..
]
```

What am I misunderstanding and doing wrong? =(

Comment: shouldnt id be in lowercase in your output, if you are only setting it as data[i].id? The code looks pretty much straight forward. what is typeId

Comment: ah. yes, you're correct. "id" is indeed lowercase in my output - I simply typed out the above rather than copypasta. typeId is the type of event that Util.checkType filters.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply call a second variable just before the `for` loop, and decrement it for every pass. For example:

```
var newData = [];

let currId = data.length - 1; // Initialize variable to store the current ID
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    if (Util.checkType(data[i].typeId)) {
        data[i].id = currId; // Store the value of currId in the id property of the current object
        newData.push(data[i]);
        console.log("newData.length", newData.length);
        console.log("data[i].id", data[i].id);
        currId--; // Decrement current ID
    }
}
console.log("newData", newData);
this.data = newData;
```